# React Locate on map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

I would like to add the module "React-leaflet-locate-control" on Map. Unfortunately, I have this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined" and I don't know how to correct this error.

Can you help me please ?

Here is my component Map :

```
import './Map.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import L from "leaflet";
import { getLat, getLng } from '../../Store.js';
import SearchBar from '../SearchBar/SearchBar.js';
import LocateControl from 'react-leaflet-locate-control';

const customMarker = new L.icon({
    iconUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/images/marker-icon.png",
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [13, 0]
});

export default class MapLeaflet extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            lat: getLat(),
            lng: getLng(),
        }
    }

    updateMarker = (e) => {
        this.props.updateMarkerPosition(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng);
        this.setState({
            lat: e.latlng.lat,
            lng: e.latlng.lng
        })
    }

    render() {
        const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng]
        const locateOptions = {
            position: 'topright',
            strings: {
                title: 'Show me where I am, yo!'
            },
            onActivate: () => {} // callback before engine starts retrieving locations
        }
        return (
            <div className="map">
                <Map center={position} zoom={13} className="map" onClick={this.updateMarker}>
                    <TileLayer
                        attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    />
                    <Marker position={position} icon={customMarker}>
                        <Popup>
                            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                        </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                    <SearchBar />
                    <LocateControl options={locateOptions} startDirectly/>
                </Map>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: This github issue seems related to your problem : https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/73#issuecomment-226392373

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`react-leaflet-locate-control` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-locate-control) is not compatible with the latest version (v2) of [`react-leaflet`](https://react-leaflet.js.org/) and in fact the similar issue has been reported [here](https://github.com/fullhdpixel/react-leaflet-locate-control/issues/6)

Since `react-leaflet-locate-control` represents a wrapper for [`leaflet-locatecontrol` plugin](https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-locatecontrol), the following custom component for `react-leaflet` could be utilized instead which offers the same functionality as `react-leaflet-locate-control`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";
import Locate from "leaflet.locatecontrol";

class LocateControl extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { options, startDirectly } = this.props;
    const { map } = this.props.leaflet;

    const lc = new Locate(options);
    lc.addTo(map);

    if (startDirectly) {
      // request location update and set location
      lc.start();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export default withLeaflet(LocateControl);
```

> **Installation**
>
> 1) install a plugin: `npm install leaflet.locatecontrol`
>
> 2) include the following CSS resources into `public/index.html`:
>
> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet.locatecontrol/dist/L.Control.Locate.min.css">
> ```

Here is [a demo](https://react-fkhpjp.stackblitz.io/) ([source code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fkhpjp))

Comment: Thank you for your help Bro :) Have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

You actually do not need any external module to get the current location in react or any other JavaScript libraries

you can use

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => //Do something with it  );
  }
```

Here is a react way :

```
 const [currentLocation, setCurrentLocation] = React.useState([0, 0]);
//change [0,0] to something that makes sense to your users in case they deny access to location.  


    useEffect(() => {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                position => 
                        setCurrentLocation([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]))
        }
    }, []);


    return (
        <Map center={currentLocation} zoom={15}>
          // the rest ie . TileLayer,Marker,Popup 
        </Map>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Typescript like me. I made it work with `v2` using below component code

```js
import L from 'leaflet';
import { withLeaflet, MapControl, MapControlProps } from 'react-leaflet';
import Locate from 'leaflet.locatecontrol';
import './Geolocate.css';

type GeolocateProps = L.Control.LocateOptions & MapControlProps;

class Geolocate extends MapControl<GeolocateProps> {
  createLeafletElement(props: GeolocateProps) {
    const { leaflet, ...options } = props;
    const locate = Locate as any;
    const lc = new locate(options);
    return lc;
  }
}
export default withLeaflet(Geolocate);
```

Additionally, you can skip including Font awesome and library's own css files and provide your own styles instead

`Geolocate.css`

```css
.leaflet-control-locate a.leaflet-bar-part div {
  background-image: url(../../images/geolocation.png);
  background-size: 22px 74px;
  background-position: top 2px left 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.leaflet-control-locate a.leaflet-bar-part div.loading {
  background-position: top -24px left 2px;
}

.leaflet-control-locate.active a.leaflet-bar-part div.locate {
  background-position: top -50px left 2px;
}

@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
  .leaflet-control-locate a.leaflet-bar-part div {
    background-image: url(../../images/geolocation-2x.png);
  }
}
```

Of course you will have to install `leaflet.locatecontrol` using `npm` first

`npm i leaflet.locatecontrol`

Hope this helps.