# React-Leaflet with leaflet.locatecontrol

Tags: gatsby, react-leaflet

I followed the answer of [React Locate on map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54099898/react-locate-on-map) and in gatsby dev-mode everything works great. But if I build my gatsby project it throws an webpack error

> "WebpackError: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function".

If I change the code from 
    `export default withLeaflet(LocateControl);`
to
    `export default withLeaflet(LocateControl);`
the build works but I get in the browser the error

> "TypeError: this.props.leaflet is undefined"

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";
import Locate from "leaflet.locatecontrol";

class LocateControl extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { options, startDirectly } = this.props;
    const { map } = this.props.leaflet;

    const lc = new Locate(options);
    lc.addTo(map);

    if (startDirectly) {
      // request location update and set location
      lc.start();
    }
  }
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
export default withLeaflet(LocateControl);
```

The locate-plugin should work but now the build is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and after a few hours this solution worked for me:

**locatecontrol.js**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";
import Locate from "leaflet.locatecontrol";

export default function LocateControl() {

  const { map } = useLeaflet();

  useEffect(() => {

    // geo locate props
    const locateOptions = {
      position: 'topright',
      maxZoom: 19,
      strings: {
          title: 'Show me where I am, yo!'
      },
      onActivate: () => {} // callback before engine starts retrieving locations
    }

    const lc = new Locate(locateOptions);
    // console.log(lc);
    lc.addTo(map);

  }, [map]);

  return null;

}
```

Import to **leaflet-map.js**

```
import LocateControl from "./locatecontrol"
```

And use LocateControl in **Map**

```
<Map>
 <LocateControl startDirectly/>
</Map>
```

I'm new in React and I'm not sure if the solution is completely correct - but I haven't come across a bug yet (we'll see :)) and the gatsby build went OK.

Maybe someone will come up with a better solution.

Comment: works well still in 2022, i just replaced the outdated `const {map} = useLeaflet()` with `const map = useMap()` and added `return () => { lc.remove() }`  in the useEffect hook to not have double buttons show up in strict mode

Answer (score 1):

## 2023 - React-Leaflet Core API Answer

To use the [React-Leaflet Core API](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/core-introduction/) to create a location control with `leaflet.locatecontrol`, one can utilize the [`createControlComponent` High-level component factory function](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/core-api/#createcontrolcomponent).

### [Here is a Live Demo hosted on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/leaflet-locate-control-core-api?file=LocateControl.tsx)

---

### Component creation:

---

#### LocateControl.tsx

```js
import { createControlComponent } from '@react-leaflet/core';
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.locatecontrol';
import 'leaflet.locatecontrol/dist/L.Control.Locate.css';

 
interface P extends L.ControlOptions {}

const { Locate } = L.Control;

function createLocateInstance(props: P) {
  const instance = new Locate(props);

  return instance;
}

export const LocateControl = createControlComponent(createLocateInstance);
```

---

### Usage

---

#### Map.tsx

```js
<MapContainer
    center={[38.9072, -77.0369]}
    zoom={8}
    zoomControl={false}
    style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%', padding: 0 }}
    whenReady={() => {}}
>
    <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
    {/* 
    Here is the custom control component. 
    Pass in any desired options as props to the component. 
    */}
    <LocateControl position="topright" />
</MapContainer>
```

Don't forget that you may need to install `@types/leaflet.locatecontrol`!

Comment: Great answer!
Just a couple of notes, as it is not explicitly specified:
- you need to run `npm install leaflet.locatecontrol @types/leaflet.locatecontrol`
- you should use `interface P extends L.Control.LocateOptions {}` as it allows to pass locatecontrol options to the component

Comment: It's also worth noting another drawback - `createControlComponent` means that the instance is fixed and will not re-render when its props are changed. This means that, if you need to re-render you'll need to obtain a `useRef` to your custom control and update it in a `useEffect` or similar.